# Is there a Markdown wiki editor that can build the browsing graph?

Tags: markdown, wiki

Trying to clean up/manage the wiki site we have. It would be great to see a graph of wiki site - really helpful to identify orphan pages, etc. Any ideas?

Comment: What kind of Wikisoftware do you use? MediaWiki, Confluence, Dokuwiki, FOSWiki...? And what do you mean with "build the browsing graph" (some like [WikiGraphBrowser](http://www.wikigraph.net/static/d3/cgmartin/WikiGraphBrowser/))

Comment: @klml That's nasty!! :)) Wow.. Yes, something like it. We have much smaller site though. The wiki is hosted by BitBucket.

Comment: so it is a very bitbucket related question. I am not so in it, hope anyone other can help.

Comment: How is it bitbucket related question? Markdown wiki can be hosted by anybody. Or be local. Visualizing graph is very independent of anything.